# 3 Cables in Switch Box and Can't Figure it out

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

I had a ceiling fan with light in a cabin that I bought.  It did not work when we bought it.  I've replaced the fan, but the light doesn't work.  The wall switch has 3 cables inside.  Attached is an actual picture and also a diagram of what's inside the box (the diagram does not include the copper grounds which are twisted all together). I think that one of these cables goes to a nearby wall outlet, one goes to the fan, and one is to the circuit box.  But I'm not sure how to determine which goes where.  I have wired this thing up a couple times and can get the fan to spin but never can get the light to come on. (yes I've made sure the pull switches were tested too).  The wall Switch is one of those Lutron Fan and Light switches.  Can someone please help guide me on this?

[image: rendering of what's inside the box]

[image: Actual image of the box]

Comment: Just so we've covered all the bases - you did check/replace the bulb right?

Comment: Remove the red from the red-black bundle.  Does one or more sockets lose power?  It may be one socket in a pair.  Turn power off at the breaker  while changing wires .

Comment: What does the wiring look like in the box for the fan? Specifically is there one house wiring cable in the fan box and is it one of the cables with the black, red, and white?

Comment: Per the answer by @longneck  you must have three wires to the Lutron combi fan/light switch. One will be an always hot (black) from the line. The other two will be "switched hots" going *to* the fan and light, respectively. In the fan box the fan switched hot goes to the fan lead (usu black) and the light switched hot goes to the light lead (usu blue).

Comment: brhans - Yes, light bulbs were checked
Harper - Yes, that wire connects the wall plug
Jim Stewart - it's a Hunter Fan, so its simple, blue/black/white.
Jim Stewart - I think you and @longneck are correct.  There is one hot wire back to the box.  I'm going to try that recommendation.

Thank you all so very, very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that the upper left wire is the fan/light, and the lower right cable is the outlet. If this is correct, then this is how you need to wire it up:

[image]

If the fan and light don't work, try reversing the red and black wires connected to the FAN and LIGHT terminals of the switch.

If that still doesn't work, you'll need to identify the cable bring power to the box. If it's not the cable in the upper right, then you'll need to investigate the wiring in the fan box or the outlet box to make any progress.

Comment: I think what you have here is probably right.  yes, I think the upper left is the fan/light, the upper right is the outlet on the wall, and the lower right is what connects to the fuse panel.  If your drawing is correct, then I will pigtail a black wire off of the joins between upper right and bottom right - correct?  THANKS SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: Based on your photo, yes. You will add a pigtail to the existing wirenut on the black/black/red wires, and connect the pigtail to the LINE terminal on your switch.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the lower right cable would be from the fuse box, because it has a red traveler wire, whereas the fuse box would be sending white (neutral), black (line), and ground. Just pointing this out, as the comment suggesting so is contrary to the provided answer.